# Call parent's activity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

If I'm inside a Fragment how can I call a parent's activity?

Comment: by calling getActivity()

Comment: Just call getActivity();

Comment: well i did.but still the method wasn't visible.

Comment: You should actually use requireActivity() rather than getActivity()

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, Its right by calling getActivity and cast it with parent activity to access its methods or variables `((ParentActivityName)getActivity())`

Try this one.

`ParentActivityName` is parent class name

Comment: What if we don't know the name? Example: i am making sdk and it has all fragments in it. I cant ask the sdk user to rename his/her activity. So how to get reference without knowing the name?

Comment: How would you like to use that reference?

Comment: I got it. My use case was to make n fragments in a library and provide to Merchants. I would not  know which Activity they would be using the fragments in. It seems making an interface, overriding it in activity and getting a callback from activity seems to be the best practice and in my scenario very helpful..

Comment: @kay Cool, that's the way!

Comment: Does it has potential for memory leaks? even though I don't store any reference to the parent `Activity`?

Answer (score 17):

**2021 UPDATE**

As it's told in the comments, `Fragment#onAttach(Activity)` [is deprecated starting from API 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.app.Activity)). Instead:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context ctx) {
    super.onAttach(ctx);
    
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        // Only attach if the caller context is actually an Activity
        if (ctx instanceof Activity) {
          mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) ctx;
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new ClassCastException(ctx.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The most proper way is to **make your `Activity` implement an `Interface` and use listeners**. That way the `Fragment` isn't tied to any specific `Activity` keeping it reusable. Into the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

That way, you make the `Activity` listen to the fragment when it's attached to it.

**See also:**

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: `onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated, use `onAttach(Context context)` instead

Answer (score 1):

Simply call your parent activity using getActivity() method.

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) getActivity().findView(R.id.your_view);
```