# how to access UI elements in parent activity from fragment

Tags: android

parent activity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LockerCodeActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/ctrlActivityIndicator"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="false"
     />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_results"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inflate the fragment in the parent activity onCreate function

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment scannerFragment = new ScanFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, scannerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Working great so far... now how do I hide the progressbar?
This is what I've tried

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ctrlActivityIndicator);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return view;
    }
```

I get a null pointer exception

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Since you want the Activity's views, you're going to want to do this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ctrlActivityIndicator);
```

You call `getActivity()` to get the Activity instance then you use `findViewById()` as normal (provided that `R.id.ctrlActivityIndicator` is part of the Activity layout, you won't get NPEs).

Comment: What about a possible NPE from `getActivity()`?

Comment: @EdLee we have to handle that case in code itself, checking for null before making relevant calls.

Answer (score 3):

This didn't work for me unitl i cast the result of getActivity to the parent activity.  See link below:
[Call parent's activity from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354279/call-parents-activity-from-a-fragment)

Comment: It is good practice to include the relevant information from the link in your answer. What if the link breaks in the future?

Comment: As a thumb rule, you should always cast the getActivity() method call to the activity it supposedly returning per se the logic of your code. And to safely do that you make a check befor casting. Example below, to cast the activity returned by getActivity method inside fragment to MainActivity

if (getActivity instanceof MainActivity){
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
}

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).UI_COMPONENT_NAME
```

to access the ui component of the parent activity.

UI_COMPONENT_NAME is the name of the component as initialised in the ParentActivity.