# How to use base activity in fragment?

Tags: java, android

Here i implemented a [emoji-keyboard.](https://github.com/edsilfer/emoji-keyboard/wiki/Development)
For the use of this library , activity extended to EmojiCompatActivity.

```
prepareKeyboard(EmojiCompatActivity activity, EmojiEditText input
```

This is working well in activity. While using in fragment i tried this one

```
prepareKeyboard((ActivityName)getActivity,input)
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends EmojiCompatActivity {}
```

And fregment class is

```
public class PagerEmojKeyboard extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emoji_keyboard, container, false);

    EmojiEditText userMessageInput = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_message);
    EmojiKeyboardLayout emojiKeyboardLayout=(EmojiKeyboardLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.keyboard_emoj);
    emojiKeyboardLayout.prepareKeyboard((MainActivity) this.getActivity(),userMessageInput);

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354279/call-parents-activity-from-a-fragment its ok. whats your problem?

Comment: Emoji keyboard is not showing when used in fragment

Comment: Just cast the `getActivity` to your desire activity

Comment: please get in touch for today , currently not possible to try all masters code , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the base activity as `this.activity`.

Sometimes, while using fragments, the above method also works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the method onCreateView you shouldn't have problems but if you have other method there is a View variable that you must have as a global for use throughout the class.