# How to get parent activity from Support V4 Fragment?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-fragments

I am a bit of a noob attempting to pass data between a fragment (living inside a tab layout) and the activity that runs the fragment.

I have found a solution here, but I am unable to call the parent activity from the fragment.

[Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Looking up multiple answers, they all say the same thing

CALL getActivity()!!

[Call parent's activity from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354279/call-parents-activity-from-a-fragment)

It doesn't exist. I am using the Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.

I can access a property this.Activity, but it's calling a random FragmentActivity when this is being hosted on an AppCompatActivity.

How can I access my hosting AppCompatActivity from the support Fragment?

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. What makes you think the activity that is being returned isn't your actual activity?

Comment: Confusion over how xamarin works.

My AppCompatActivity is called NewActivity.

When I called (NewActivity)this.Activity.setOnBundleSelected() it couldn't access the setOnBundleSelected() method despite being public.

However when I call it like (this.Activity as NewActivity).setOnBundleSelected() I can now use it, so maybe I was just confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using viewmodels to pass data between activities and fragments

Comment: Thank you, is there any available resources on viewmodels where I could learn more that you could recommend.

It's very frustrating trying to figure anything out because I spend days reading, try to implement it, and find out it's years obsolete.

I feel like I keep learning variations of the same thing 5 times and I still don't know the right way.